# Responsive Email - Hide image in gmail app (iOs)

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, html-email

Is it possible to hide an image when using the mobile app for Gmail? I'm using my mobile app on iOS and have tried for 2 hours with no luck at all.

```
<style type="text/css">

     
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
            
    table.hide { display: none !important }
          
        
}

</style>

<table class="hide" align="right" width="324" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding: 40px 40px 0px 110px;"><img src="#" width="172" height="42" border="0" alt="Release"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide **only** on Gmail iOS, or for all Gmail, or what?

Comment: I want it to hide on all mobile, but I can't get it to work on gmail. The rest look fine in litmus.

Comment: Make sure you have a propre `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` structure. Gmail only supports `<style>` elements in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 1):

You code works for me, except that there are [different Gmail versions](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2016/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-after-the-2016-update/) and Gmail IMAP/POP is one that does NOT support classes/embedded CSS at all (it's completely removed). Same can be said for Android native email.

Perhaps as @HTeuMeuLeu noted, the normal structure is needed.

This is what I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width:600px) {  
      table.hide { display: none !important }
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table class="hide" align="right" width="324" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding: 0;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/172x42" width="172" height="42" border="0" alt="Release"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding: 0;">This is a test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```